# How to add nibs to a UIStackView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I'm trying to add an arbitrary amount of view from nibs into a UIStackView. The issue is that, say, if only include one view, that view grows to fill the entire stackview, instead of maintaining the proper width. Here's my code so far:

```
friendStackView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
friendStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let friendView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FriendView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FriendViewController
friendStackView.addArrangedSubview(friendView)
friendView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
friendView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```

It results in the following debug:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14eb9eb0 UIStackView:0x14ee6ed0.width == 500   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ef83f0 XXX.FriendViewController:0x14ef2090.width == 120   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14def090 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x14ee6ed0.leading == XXX.FriendViewController:0x14ef2090.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14def230 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[XXX.FriendViewController:0x14ef2090]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x14ee6ed0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ef83f0 XXX.FriendViewController:0x14ef2090.width == 120   (active)>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict here the stackView width = 500 and you're trying to give the subview which is supposed to fill the whole width 120

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14eb9eb0 UIStackView:0x14ee6ed0.width == 500   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ef83f0 XXX.FriendViewController:0x14ef2090.width == 120
```

Comment: Where is the instruction that it has to fill the whole width? Why can't it leave space at the end?

Comment: Prgrammatically or IB , add what constraints you gave it

Comment: The stack view has the width of 500, 0 trailing-trailing-bottom-top space to the superview. Equal height to the superview, which is a scrollview (the orientation is horizontal). Ideally I just want the stackview to be the minimum width needed to contain the subviews.

Comment: Got it! Removed the width constraint and called sizeToFit()

Comment: only give it top , leading and height , and when you add a subview give it a width with no height , also note when subviews total width exceeds screen width you'll not be able to scroll , so consider inserting it inside a scrollview , or use a collectionView instead

Comment: +Sh_Khan It's wrapped in a scrollview :)